# How to display red "Cancel" button in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uibutton

I am building a custom `UITableViewCell` which will be displayed while the user is downloading data from a web service, and which will include a "Cancel" button to allow them to cancel the URL connection. I'd like to emulate the look-and-feel of the "Delete" buttons which are displayed in the table editing view, like this:

[image]

**How can I create such a red button which says "Cancel" instead of "Delete" in my custom `UITableViewCell`?** It appears that the only type of button I can put in a `UITableViewCell` is a regular `UIButton` (`UIBarButtonItem` won't go anywhere except a `UIToolbar`), and Interface Builder doesn't give an option to create a red Delete-like button as a standard style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just had to create my own custom UITableViewCell, and use some Photoshop magic to figure out how to make a button that looks exactly like the iPhone Delete buttons, but saying "Cancel." It didn't take that much time.

Comment: There's an - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method for that